# How do I create typescript type definitions for react-native native ui component?

Tags: ios, typescript, react-native

Let us say that I have a react native native UI component like the one in [this example](https://medium.com/@yrezgui/create-native-ui-component-in-react-native-6f4b7fe4cc95). How do I create a typescript type definition for it, like the ones that can be imported, for example with 'npm i @types/somelib'? I didn't find explanations about how to do this in the documentation.

The idea is to be able to use the native component seamlessly in a react-native typescript project and for that I need to create the type definition for native components. So, how do I create typescript type definitions for native components?

The iOS/objc side

- FoobarView.h:

```
    #ifndef FoobarView_h
    #define FoobarView_h
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    @interface FoobarView : UITextView
    @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL teste;
    @end
    #endif
```

- FoobarView.m:

```
    #import "FoobarView.h"
    @implementation FoobarView
    -(void) setTeste:(BOOL)teste
    {
      if (teste == YES)
      {
        [self setText:@"é true"];
      }else
      {
        [self setText:@"é false"];
      }
    }
    -(BOOL)getTeste
    {
      if ([[self text] isEqual:@"é true"])
      {
        return YES;
      }else
      {
        return NO;
      }
    }
    @end
```

- FoobarManager.m

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <React/RCTViewManager.h>
    #import "FoobarView.h"
    @interface FooManager : RCTViewManager
    @end
    @implementation FooManager
    RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(FoobarView)
    RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(teste, BOOL)
    +(BOOL) requiresMainQueueSetup
    {
      return YES;
    }
    - (UIView*)view
    {
      FoobarView *v = [[FoobarView alloc]init];
      return v;
    }
    @end
```

So, FoobarView is a native iOS view, written in objc. It is not a react native  ui component. I am using a simple descendent from UITextView but it could be anything, like a SceneKit view.

To use it in the javascript side of react native, I'm using this code in FoobarView.js:

```
import { requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native';
module.exports = requireNativeComponent('FoobarView');
```

And, finally, i can use FoobarView in a render block:

```
    <FoobarView style={{width:'100%', height:30}} teste={true} />
```

My question is:
How can I define that FoobarView, something defined in the ios, has the property teste, and that teste is a boolean?

Comment: I will look it up shortly but why don't just write the component in typescript? Or is it not in your power to decide if the project is in js or ts?

Comment: @Elias It's a native component, written in objective-c.

Comment: edited my answer. Should not be too different

Comment: How about a `react-native native PureComponent` how native are we going to get :D

Comment: The reason I am insisting on writing native ui components (that is, UIViews that react native can understand and use to assemble the view) is that there is no 3d library for RN that is flexible && works on RN 0.6x. So I decided to write my own, for my own proposes, and to do so, I must understand how to create native ui views.

Comment: Yes but the "tutorial" you said you were following still exports the component through a javascript file. Just write a definition file for that file like I have described below.

Answer (score 5):

I guess for the topic starter my answer is a bit late but for everyone else who's facing the same issue I solved it with this approach:

```
import { requireNativeComponent, HostComponent } from 'react-native';

// Specify all your properties
interface Props {
  teste: boolean;
}

const FoobarView: HostComponent<Props> = requireNativeComponent('FoobarView');

module.exports = FoobarView;
```

TS will recognize only `teste` property but in your example you also pass `style` property to the component, so in order to support it as well you should either specify it explicitly in the `Props` above, e.g.

```
interface Props {
  teste: boolean;
  style: ViewStyle;
}
```

Or you can extend View properties (if they're suitable for your usecase), e.g.

```
interface Props extends ViewProps {
  teste: boolean;
}
```

Comment: I am using react-native 0.61.4 but `HostComponent` doesn't resolve in 'react-native'.

Comment: @Rishabh876 `HostComponent` shoud be available from v0.62 and higher

Answer (score 0):

For React native versions below 0.62

Make sure to create .tsx file like this.

```
//FoobarView.tsx

import React, { ReactElement } from 'react'
import { requireNativeComponent, ViewProps } from 'react-native'

interface Props extends ViewProps {
    teste: boolean
}
const _FoobarView = requireNativeComponent('FoobarView')

const FoobarView = (props: Props): ReactElement<Props> => {
    return <_FoobarView {...props} style={props.style} />
}

export default FoobarView
```

Inspired from: https://shopify.engineering/creating-native-components-accept-react-native-subviews